# How to get code through the url in formed in php for oauth

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am using this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632721.aspx

I need it to run without user interaction so when I have the following in index.php

```
$goToUrl = $authorizationUrlBase . '?' . http_build_query($queryParams);
```

what do I do with this to get the code in php? I have checked for testing purpose using

```
header("Location:" .$goToUrl);
```

that it has `code` in the url formed but if I use above line of code in php, it gets stuck at the new window.

How do I deal with this? I do I fetch that `code` value without having to redirecting anywhere.

**I need it to run without user interaction since it needs to be run as a cron job. I am using Bing ads api.

Comment: The `header()` code is used to redirect a browser to the URL. If you're not using this interactively, it has no effect.

Comment: If you're doing this from a cron job, you need to use `cURL` to load the URL. It makes use of cookies, so you'll need to use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options to save and send cookies. And `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to follow the redirect that it sends.

Comment: OAuth is primarily designed for interactive web pages. If you're automating this outside a browser, there might be an API you can use that just takes an authentication token directly, so you won't need all this complexity.

Comment: @Barmar: Oh that sounds good. Could you please point me to one?

Comment: @Barmar: Also, in the example, how did they really intend to connect it. The index.php in example seems to be redirecting on click of the button too but how are they using and saving it for the flow to work?

Comment: Yes, I understand header would be use less here. Was only testing

Comment: OAuth is used for things like web pages that allow you to login with your Facebook or Google username/password. You start at a page on your site, it links to a URL at FB/Google that authenticates you, then it redirects back to your site with a token that can be used to confirm that the login succeed and get details about the user's account. When you validate that token, you can then set a session variable saying that they logged in to your site.

Comment: This looks like the starting point in documentation of the Bing Ads SOAP API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-overview-getting-started-php-with-web-services.aspx

Comment: @Barmar: Ammmm.. Where does it say how to get through authentication without user interaction on that page please?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-getting-started.aspx. You can send a Username and Password instead of an OAuth token.

Comment: They were not giving it off and are deprecating it. Just needed to know if it is even possible to have oauth work the normal way with code/access token without having user interaction at all